# Program terminating on ConnectionError though the exception is handled in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

In my prgram, I am using requests module to call the url. If in case of network error or any other issues, I am handling the error. In the exception block below, using the timer I am calling the service(url) again after specific time interval. I tried to run the program without network, the response from requests is

> "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api//issubmitted/2020/3/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))"

But the program fails to call the timer. It just exits with Process finished with exit code 1073741845.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
import sys

class ShowScreen():

    def call_api(self):
        resp1 = CallServices.is_submitted(self)
        if resp1['isLocked'] == False:
            Main()


class CallServices():

    def is_submitted(self):
        url = '%s/issubmitted/%s/%d/%s' % (url_sub, year, month, username)
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, 
     requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) as e:
            print("error")
            api_logger.debug('DEBUG- IsSubmitted Response: %s', e)
            timer = QTimer(QApplication.instance())
            interval =  1000
            timer.setInterval(interval)
            timer.timeout.connect(lambda: ShowScreen.call_api())
            timer.start()


class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

class MainClass():
    def start_timer(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        Main()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MainClass()
    m.start_timer()
```

Comment: There is a good chance that the "timer" variable looses scope and gets deleted due to python's reference counting. Try `self.timer = timer = QTimer(QApplication.instance())`. If `self` dies due to reference counting then you may want to save the variable to the class.

Comment: How do you start everything? Do you create a QApplication?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Added the main block. please check.